# java Api catalog? komodoedit java auto complete feature

Tags: java, autocomplete, komodo, komodoedit

Hi by default komodo edit supports the following languages for its auto completion feature by default:

- Ruby: require, class modules (on . and ::), class variables and methods, method calltips.
- Python
- Perl
- PHP
- XSLT
- XML
- Tcl

I am programming in java at the moment, and I need to have the auto completion feature with that language. Can someone please tell me where i can download it or how i can enable it. thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
If i go to preferences, code intelligence, there is an option to add API catalog from my hard drive. so there must be a java api catalog? how can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Komodo's goal is to provide the same features than Java/.net IDE but this time for dynamic languages such as Perl, Python or Ruby. And as said in [this post](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/does-it-work-with-java) there is already a better integration of Java (or .net) in other specialized IDEs.

You should look at [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: firs thank you for replying. ive edited my post. There is an option to add an api catalog from my hard drive, so there must be a way of adding a java api catalog.